# Changing the Aspect Ratio without distortion and without black bars around the edges (depending upon the screen size it is played on)

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a set of two PowerPoint presentations that I have coded using VBA to interact together (one has buttons that allow navigation in another). Originally these were going to be displayed on static screens and so I had defined the sizes of these to fit the screens perfectly so that they filled the screens and sat next to each other to look like one application. However, due to Covid this is now going to be displayed in lecture theatres on a projector, using different laptops each time, and so I need the presentations to be dynamic and adjust to the screens of the user.

I managed to code such so that the presentations fill the screens depending upon the user. See my code (note that both presentations aren't opened by this code as I also have code externally so that the entire thing can be opened externally with a click of a VBScript File):

```
Sub Resize_Presentations()

Dim PPT1 As Object
Set PPT1 = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
Set PPT1 = Presentations("Stand-up Wall - From Drive\Stand Up Title Page - With Macros.pptm")

Dim PPT2 As Object
Set PPT2 = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
Set PPT2 = Presentations("Stand Up Summary and Breakdowns - With Macros.pptm")

'define screen height and width for resizing'
PPT1.Application.ActiveWindow.WindowState = ppWindowMaximized
windWidth = Application.Width
windHeight = Application.Height

'minimise windows for playing presentations'
PPT1.Application.ActiveWindow.WindowState = ppWindowMinimized
PPT2.Application.ActiveWindow.WindowState = ppWindowMinimized

'play title presentation in defined size'
With PPT1.SlideShowSettings
    .ShowType = ppShowTypeSpeaker
    
With .Run
    .Top = 0
    .Left = 0
    .Width = windWidth / 3
    .Height = windHeight
End With
End With

'play breakdown and summary presentation in defined size'
With PPT2.SlideShowSettings
    .ShowType = ppShowTypeSpeaker
    
With .Run
    .Top = 0
    .Left = windWidth / 3
    .Width = (windWidth / 3) * 2
    .Height = windHeight
End With
End With

End Sub
Sub Open_Presentation()

Dim Ret
Dim Ret2

Dim PPT1 As Object
Set PPT1 = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")

Dim PPT2 As Object
Set PPT2 = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")

Ret = IsWorkBookOpen("C:\Users\RobinsonH7\Desktop\Stand-up Wall - From Drive\Stand Up Title Page - With Macros.pptm")
Ret2 = IsWorkBookOpen("C:\Users\RobinsonH7\Desktop\Stand-up Wall - From Drive\Stand Up Summary and Breakdowns - With Macros.pptm")

If Ret = True And Ret2 = False Then

Set PPT1 = Presentations("Stand-up Wall - From Drive\Stand Up Title Page - With Macros.pptm")
Set PPT2 = Presentations.Open(FileName:="C:\Users\RobinsonH7\Desktop\Stand-up Wall - From Drive\Stand Up Summary and Breakdowns - With Macros.pptm")

Call Resize_Presentations

Else: MsgBox "Close all stand-up wall slides"
End If

End Sub
Function IsWorkBookOpen(FileName As String)
    Dim ff As Long, ErrNo As Long

    On Error Resume Next
    ff = FreeFile()
    Open FileName For Input Lock Read As #ff
    Close ff
    ErrNo = Err
    On Error GoTo 0

    Select Case ErrNo
    Case 0:    IsWorkBookOpen = False
    Case 70:   IsWorkBookOpen = True
    Case Else: Error ErrNo
    End Select
End Function
```

Things I have tried adding to this:

- Code that resizes the actual slides at the same time depending upon the screen of who is opening the presentation, this didn't work as it re-scaled all the items on the pages and made it a complete mess. Also tried grouping all objects and doing this and it still didn't work.
- I tried trying to access the MasterSlide object and resize this to see if this would work in just increasing the slide size and not the objects. However, I couldn't get this to work, it seems the MasterSlide object can't be accessed directly.
- Using a blank presentation that resizes and then copies and pastes everything from the other presentation so things are positioned correctly, however this messed up the layout and was very very very slow and I would prefer to avoid this option.

Ideally I want to just adjust the way the presentations are presented when played, almost like the presentation is stretched or zoomed to the fit the space. Any help would be much apprieciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The syntax to reach the slide master is a little arcane due to PowerPoint development history. You refer to **Designs** instead of SlideMaster! Here is a statement that assesses whether there is more than one slide master:

```
If ActivePresentation.Designs.Count > 1 Then
```

To act on slide master shapes in a presentation with more than one slide master:

```
For Z = 1 To ActivePresentation.Designs.Count
    For Each objShape In ActivePresentation.Designs(Z).SlideMaster.Shapes
```

After resizing, your code then has to find every shape to resize them back to their original proportions. In all versions of PowerPoint after 2010, presentation height remains constant at 7.5" and only the width varies. 10" wide for 4x3, 12" for 16x10 and 13.33" for 16x9. So you really only have to change the width of graphics to bring them back to their correct proportions.

As an alternative approach, you can use an add-in like [PPTools Resize](http://pptools.com/resize/FAQ00008_Buy_-PPTools_Resize--_Where_and_how_much-.htm). Or you can use a SuperTheme that has aspect ratio variants for 4x3, 16x10 and 16x9, which will cover 99.99% of the displays out there. Here's more information about how SuperThemes work: [SuperThemes](http://www.brandwares.com/bestpractices/2018/02/brandwares-custom-superthemes/)

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for the reply, this is really useful to know about accessing the Master. I have a question, does the height remain constant even if I have used the custom sizing as I am have two presentations that are different sizes - one is set up to fill a third of the screen and the other two thirds. For resizing do I just add the code to resize based upon the screen size to the loop after `For Each objShape In ActivePresentation.Designs(Z).SlideMaster.Shapes`?

Comment: You can treat the height as constant because it's always filling 100% of the screen height. If you only have 1 slide master in each deck, then you can use `ActivePresentation.Designs(1).SlideMaster.Shapes` After setting the window dimensions, then loop through the slide master shapes and set their width.